AWS cognito authentication in android studio
i am trying to integrate the cognito authentication in my android app but getting stuck into dependecies error or mainactivity code where i am implementing it , do anyone have any idea or have clear steps to integrate the cognito authentication into android app ?
I tried following gpt steps

created user pool and client id
2.created identity pool
added depedencies into gradle.kt
added imports and sign in & sign out function in mainactivity and verification activity
watched many videos to solve it but the problem remained as it is


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
